# Two questions related to installing frameworks with CocoaPods

Tags: cocoapods

In the following code what does the first line in the Podfile do?  Many of the sample projects I've seen do not include this line.

Why do I not need to specify a path to Alamofire/Image as is done with SwiftJSON?

[image: CocoaPods Podfile]

Comment: It's omitted because it's the "default" search for pods. Pods are listed in it, that's why when you do `pod 'Alamofire'` it knows where to look for it. For the other one, it's just specifying where to get it.

Comment: Hi @Larme .  Thanks very much!